# Devons- nous écrire « OK », « O.K. » ou « ok » ?

Tags: anglais, étymologie, orthographe, histoire

Ce mot qui nous vient de l'anglais, m’interpelle. Je me demandais comment nous devions l'écrire? Depuis quelques mois, je me pose cette question alors qu'avant je l'écrivais toujours "ok".

Après quelques recherches j'ai trouvé [comment il devait s'écrire en anglais](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25617/difference-between-ok-and-okay).

De même en français, le Larousse nous donne [O.K. ou okay](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/OK/55817?q=OK#55458).

Alors que d'autres mentionnent « ok » ou d'autres formes. De plus, le correcteur automatique du site me propose « OK »… Ce qui me rend confus.

Mais comment devons-nous l'écrire en français et surtout pourquoi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Comme on l'a dit, [*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/OK/55817?q=ok#55458) donne adverbe et adj. invariable « O.K. » ou « okay ».
- Le [*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/o.k) donne « O.K. » en majuscule, loc. adv., et mentionne « [*okay*](https://books.google.com/books?id=HaEbAQAAIAAJ&q=%22bonheur%20d%27occasion%22%20okay%20roy&dq=%22bonheur%20d%27occasion%22%20okay%20roy&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidt_-r18vKAhWFmoMKHUpYC3kQ6AEINjAF) » en référant à [*Bonheur d'occasion*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonheur_d'occasion_%28roman%29) (G. Roy, éd. *Pascal*, 1945 ; l'éd. de 2009 de *Boréal* utilise « O.K. » uniquement !)
- Le *LBU14* utilise « O. K. » (aux §§ 190 et 1108).
- Au *DHLF/Rey*, on note « O. K. » avec semble-t-il l'espace comme au *LBU* ; rare avant la 2<sup>ème</sup> guerre mondiale, fréquent depuis, se substituant à toutes sortes de réponses [positives](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17550) ([2](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/OK/598771)).
- [*Collins*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american-french/ok) en ligne présente ses exemples en français avec « OK » tout court.

Il faut observer que c'est attesté essentiellement 30 ans après l'attestation en langue anglaise, donc en 1869, dans sa forme en **attribut** avec le verbe être : *tout est O. K.*.<sup>1</sup> La première attestation à l'écrit en langue française apparaît dans un récit de la pose, par le navire [*Great-Eastern*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS_Great_Eastern#Le_premier_c.C3.A2ble_transatlantique), de [câbles](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A2ble_sous-marin#/media/File:Atlantic_cable_Map.jpg) de télégramme transatlantique entre l'Irlande à Terre-Neuve dans le Golfe St-Laurent, que relate une revue française ([L'Année scientifique et industrielle](https://books.google.com/books?id=-EIpAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA111&dq=L%27Ing%C3%A9nieur,%20ao%C3%BBt%201869%20%22cha%C3%AEne%20sans%20fin%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKi9nprcrKAhWGmIMKHdr0CdAQ6AEIIzAB#v=snippet&q=%22cha%C3%AEne%20sans%20fin%22&f=false)). L'**interjection** pour l'assentiment est [attestée](https://books.google.com/books?id=InVPKNDYekEC&dq=L.%20Durtain%2C%20Conqu%C3%AAtes%20du%20monde.%20Captain%20O.K&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22o.k.%22) plus tard, en 1931. Vu la présence de points, (et le fait qu'un [*ngram*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ok%2Co.k.%2Cokay%2COK%2CO.K.%2COKAY%2C%28ok%29-%28o.k.%29-%28okay%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cok%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Co.k.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cokay%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COK%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CO.K.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COKAY%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28ok%29%20-%20%28o%20.%20k.%29%20-%20%28okay%29%3B%2Cc0) n'en tienne pas compte) il s'avère impossible de faire un constat à partir du corpus *Books* (Google).

La forme avec les points rappelle l'explication de l'origine en anglais, mais la majuscule est vraiment l'apanage de la langue anglaise, et la prononciation de la lettre K dans l'expression est anglaise (o-quai vs. o-ka). Le fait d'avoir une variante en minuscule et une variante en majuscule permet à mon avis d'avoir plus de nuances pour marquer à l'écrit la force du propos (*ok... "ok"... ok!... OK!!!*). Par ailleurs un francophone qui n'aurait jamais vu ou entendu O.K. pourrait prononcer *okay* naturellement en français. Enfin certains [conseillent](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1350) de laisser généralement tomber les points abbréviatifs dans les *sigles* pour fins de *simplification* et d'*uniformisation*. Tout ceci n'a aucun impact sur l'emploi, fréquent, dans la langue parlée.

Quant à l'emprunt, [généralement](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=emprunt&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) la dynamique varie selon le type et mène parfois à la francisation etc. Le stade auquel est rendu *O.K.* est sans doute différent, par exemple, de celui du [*toast*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toast) après sa plus longue cuisson : double réemprunt à l'anglais à partir de *tostee* en français du 13<sup>e</sup> qu'on avait prêté au 15<sup>e</sup>, dénombrable pour la tranche de pain (*contra* langue anglaise), prend la marque du pluriel sans prononciation (un(e, Qc.) toast = des toasts), et semble donc complètement intégré à la langue. L'orthographe acceptée de *O.K.* pourrait certainement évoluer...

---

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>C'est-à-dire *tout à fait correct* ; non sans faire penser à *everything is all right* ; on notera qu'en anglais aussi il y a un [développement](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=OK&allowed_in_frame=0) dans les types d'emplois, généralement le nom d'abord, puis le verbe ; voir aussi rappel de l'origine [anglaise](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=ok&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) ([2](https://books.google.ca/books?id=t6AhAQAAMAAJ&dq=saturday%20review%20literature%20ol%20korrect&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=korrect)), [française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/o.k).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

L'étymologie réelle de cette expression porte encore confusion à ce que j'ai pu lire en complément des sources que tu cites.

Il semble que le dictionnaire français considère l'origine comme étant "oll korrect", en ce cas O.K. serait l'orthographe juste puisque l'on fait un sigle de cette expression (différence [sigle/acronyme](http://www.les-abreviations.com/definitions.html)). Comme W.C. dans le temps.

---

Aparently, etymology of this word is still questionable.

If the origin is an acronym from "oll korrect", then O.K. seems legit to use. As we used W.C.

Answer (score 2):

**L'étymologie O.K.** (venant de all correct => all correct => OK) semble partagée également là:

[wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/OK_%28expression%29) qui cite Alain Rey propose également:

> En 1840, le terme a été utilisé par des partisans de Martin Van
>   Buren, élu à la présidence des États-Unis en 1837, et surnommé « Old
>   Kinderhook » (« le vieux de Kinderhook ») du nom de son village natal.
>   Un club de soutien s'est créé à New York sous l'appellation de « O. K.
>   Club » (23 mars 1840).

[Libération](http://www.liberation.fr/societe/2014/03/22/ok-une-expression-qui-fete-ses-175-ans_989160) en 2014: indique, en plus de cette origine:

> Les deux lettres apparaissent pour la première fois le 23 mars 1839
>   dans un journal de Boston : «O.K.», mot symbole de l’Amérique, est
>   devenu en 175 ans une expression universelle.
>
> C’est le Boston Morning Post, à l’époque le journal le plus populaire
>   des Etats-Unis, qui le premier utilise dans l’un de ses articles ce
>   «O.K.» qui fera le tour du monde.
>
> Pour son spécialiste, le professeur d’anglais Allan Metcalf, auteur de
>   «O.K., l’histoire improbable du plus grand mot de l’Amérique», c’est
>   l’expression «la plus souvent prononcée ou écrite sur toute la
>   planète», devant «maman».

Il y a encore l'origine militaire ( [Ministère français de la Défense](http://www.defense.gouv.fr/actualites/articles/l-origine-du-mot-ok)):

> Selon une hypothèse, OK trouverait son origine au cours de la guerre
>   de Sécession qui ravagea les États-Unis de 1861 à 1865.
>
> Après les combats, un officier avait pour mission de noter dans un
>   rapport le nombre de victimes recensées. Lorsqu'une bataille se
>   passait sans pertes d'hommes, la mention était de "zero killed" (zéro
>   mort), expression vite abrégée en "0.K.". Rapidement, ce "0.K." devint
>   synonyme de "tout va bien".
>
> Par la suite, ce terme militaire est passé dans le langage courant
>   américain avant de franchir l'Atlantique et d'entrer dans notre
>   vocabulaire de tous les jours.

C'est donc considéré comme un acronyme (comme *cqfd*, *sgdg*, ...).

**Question plus générale de l'écriture des acronymes:**

Les quatre formes ok, o.k. OK, O.K. sont utilisables.

**Normalement, il faudrait mettre des points, et plutôt des majuscules.
La forme la plus rigoureuse serait O.K.**

Par simplicité, les gens omettent souvent les points, et emploient minuscules ou majuscules: ok ou OK.

**Plus précisément pour OK, on trouve surtout *ok* et *OK* (rarement *O.K.* et encore plus rarement *o.k.* )**

voir des explications très détaillées sur ce [lien](https://www.druide.com/enquetes/pour-les-cingl%C3%A9s-des-sigles-et-les-accros-des-acronymes) .

Comment: L'hypothèse de la Défense est bien originale !

Answer (score 0):

Si on recherche la fréquence des variantes dans [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=o.k.%2C+O.K.%2C+okay%2C+OK&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Co.k.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CO.K.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cokay%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COK%3B%2Cc0) c'est evident que, malgré les argumentations excellents par rapport à l'Oklahoma et l'étymologie,  «OK» est la forme le plus commune.

Le 9<sup>é</sup> dictionnaire de l'Académie française n'a pas les mots «O.K.», «ok»,  «o.k.»,  «OK» ni «okay».

On peut trouver d' [autres locutions](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/okay) pour exprimer les sens auquels ils réfèrent.

Par example:

1. **D'accord** pour exprimer (**2**) [consentement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/accord)
2. **Ça va bien** pour exprimer (**II**.4,5)[comportement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/aller)

---

If one searches for the frequency of the variants using [Google's ngram-viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=o.k.%2C+O.K.%2C+okay%2C+OK&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Co.k.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CO.K.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cokay%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COK%3B%2Cc0) it is clear that, despite the excellent arguments in other posts referencing the state of Oklahoma and etymology, "OK" is the commonest form.

The 9<sup>th</sup> edition of the Académie française dictionary does not have the words "ok", "o.k.", "OK", "O.K.", nor "okay".

It is possible to find other expressions to express the exact sense in which the catch-all "okay" is used.

For example:

1. **D'accord** to express (see definition 2) [agreement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/accord).
2. **Ça va bien** to express (see definitions **II**.4, **II**.5) [state of being](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/aller)

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax  Good point about absence not being equivalent to forbidding a word. I did notknow about the _Emplois fautifs_ section and assumed that if they did not list it then it was considered inadvisable.  I'll modify the answer based on that.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax  :)  Thank you again.  Just noticed your answer with the point about ngram corpus not distinguishing the interjection. I was going to fall back on simply saying:  "just use what's common"

Comment: You're welcome. But that's the thing, results including the dots are subsumed in the output of what you see for the word without the dots. Anyways, personally I don't care much for writing it even though I find the Q. interesting. I use it constantly in speech but outside of colloquial texting/email or transcribing speech, I'd never write "tout est O.K." or the interjection in a formal written text, etc. Thanks!